# Is there a way to access Microsoft Academic data set listed on Microsoft DataMarket?

Tags: data-request, api, odata

The data set is listed here: https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/mrc/microsoftacademic

It supports the Open Data Protocol. However, when I access it on Chrome, e.g., with https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/MRC/MicrosoftAcademic/v2/Domain?$top=2, the result is:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code/>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
We are currently experiencing problems with the backend database. If you continue to receive this error, please contact us (https://datamarket.azure.com/support).
 We appreciate your patience and will continue to improve the product based on your feedback. -- Reference #: 36dd1702-5a3e-483f-a3a6-35347222af36
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Here is the returned result on IE 8:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <m:code /> 
  <m:message xml:lang="en-US">We are currently experiencing problems with the backend database. If you continue to receive this error, please contact us (https://datamarket.azure.com/support). We appreciate your patience and will continue to improve the product based on your feedback. -- Reference #: 356e0d00-ef73-4c9e-9e01-3e6854a5fe2f</m:message> 
  </m:error>
```

Did I do something wrong? Or the data set is just faulty?

Comment: first thought: hit that url in ie or edge. report back.

Comment: @albert: I only have IE 8 for testing. The returned result is updated in the question. It seems same error message. Thanks.

Comment: ok, well i see it in chrome and ff....contact azure team, maybe that api is shut down

Comment: I think this is a programming question better suited for http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I could not move the question, so please move if you could. By the way, the service is confirmed shut down now. Thanks.